# Is there any way to get the unit and value of the given duration using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have duration value as below:

`var duration = "7 days";`

From the above I want to get the object which has value and unit,like:

```
time {
  value: 7,
  unit: days
}
```

I know that I can get the value and unit using `JavaScript`. But I'm thinking it would be better if i can do this using some method of `momentjs`.
I went through `momentjs` documentation, but I didn't find one.

Is there any way to achieve this using `momentjs`?

Comment: Can you tell what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to two date-time values, say `start` and `end`. So i got the difference between these two days using moment say for ex: `2 days` or `3 weeks` but for templating I need to pass the two values separately as `time` and `unit`. I don't want to pass this string(ex:`2 days`) directly.

Comment: did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 1):

from the docs you can get:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/as-json/

```
moment.duration().toJSON();
```

When serializing a duration object to JSON, it will be be represented as an ISO8601 string.

```
JSON.stringify({
    postDuration : moment.duration(5, 'm')
}); // '{"postDuration":"PT5M"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function (in .ts) to get the timescale :

```
export enum Unit {
    minute,
    hour,
    day,
    week,
    month
};

export type Duration = {
    value   : number;
    unit    : keyof typeof Unit;
}

const getTimescale = ( input : string ) => { 
    const duration = moment.duration(input);
    const units = Object.keys(Unit).filter(k => typeof Unit[k as any] === "number").reverse() as Array<keyof typeof Unit>;

    let result = {} as Duration;
    for (let i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
        let value = duration.get(units[i] as keyof typeof Unit);
        if( result.unit && value ){
            if( moment.duration(duration, units[i] as keyof typeof Unit).subtract( moment.duration( result.value, result.unit )) > moment.duration(0) ){
                return { value, unit : units[i] as keyof typeof Unit }
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        };
        result = { value, unit : units[i] as keyof typeof Unit };
    };

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation today and I found a simple solution.

In my case, I had to say to the user that he could select a range of 1 month (max). But whether the user selects 30 days or 34 days, `humanize()` returns "1 month" in both cases. That's how I ended up here. Hope this will help some people to save some time.

### Solution

So instead of using `moment.duration().humanize()`, using `moment.duration().days()` or `.asDays()` did the trick.

You can also use `.get(unit)` to get the remainder.
Example : if you have a duration of 31 days, then do `duration.get('days')`, it returns `1`.

Same goes for every unit. See : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations

### toJSON() ?

Nice try, but moment.duration().toJSON() as proposed in another answer won't be of any help in this situation because it returns an object with a string in the form of "PT5M", not really what we wanted.

See: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/as-json/